# tabbar and tabbarview in flutter: When a form field in my second tab takes focus, I'm taken back to the first tab

Tags: flutter, tabs

I'm kinda new to flutter. I created a page containing two tabs. The first contains a menu with images and the second contains a form. I manage to navigate between the tabs. But when I click on the field of my form (contained in the second tab), as soon as the keyboard appears, the form disappears and I am brought back to the first tab.

```
 class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _MyScreenStateState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen > with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  static final _formRechargeKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static TextEditingController codeRechargeController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    TabController _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);

    return Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        child: Text(titrePage,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 25,color: Colors.white,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline),),
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: TabBar(
                            controller: _tabController,
                            tabs: [
                              Tab(child: Text("Achat de crédit"),),
                              Tab(child: Text("Recharge de crédit"),),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 500,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: TabBarView(
                          controller: _tabController,
                          children: [
                            _widgetAchatCredit(listeItems),
                            _widgetRechargeCredit(),

                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the widget code for my second tab. There is a list that comes after the form

```
 Widget _widgetRechargeCredit(){
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: w_margin_top),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Card(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 8),
              Align(child: Text("Formule de recharge"),alignment: Alignment.center),
              Form(
                key: _formRechargeKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                        controller: codeRechargeController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Code de recharge",
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text("Recharger compteur"),
                        onPressed: (){
                          print("ok");
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
);
```

}
When I initialize the key of the form in initState this key is not recognized in my widget I am returned **Undefined name '_formRechargeKey'**

Comment: Solved !!! I solved the problem by initializing my controller in initState

Comment: Close your question if it is solved.